# How do I know which list item was clicked?

Tags: java, android

I have a `ListView` filled with items.  I'd like to set an `onClickListener` to show details about the item that was clicked.  How can I determine which item was clicked within the `onClickListener`?  The `View`, or `v` has a lot of methods available that I've looked through and don't see anything pertaining to getting the object clicked on.

```
    //populate the activity list
    ListView teamsListView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.teamsListView);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> listItem;
    for (TeamSet teamSet : response.getTeamSetList()) {
        listItem = new HashMap<String, String>();
            listItem.put("name", teamSet.getName());
            //listItem.put("teamCount", Integer.toString(teamSet.getTeams().size()));

        listData.add(listItem);
    }
    teamsListView.setAdapter(
            new SimpleAdapter(
                    context,
                    listData,
                    R.layout.teams_list_row,
                    new String[]{"name"},
                    new int[]{R.id.teamsTeamListName}
            )
    );

    //show details on a team
    TextView team = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.teamsTeamListName);
    team.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //how do I know which item was clicked?  I want to load more details on the item...
        }
    });
```

Comment: [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)?

Comment: I like how I got 2 down votes for asking a question... some people on this site....

Comment: I think it's because you didn't show any research effort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a OnItemClickListener not a onCLickListener

**You do something like this:**

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
        String selectedFromList =(String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));

      }                 
});
```

Hope this helped.